# React - this.setState and this.forceUpdate doesn't update state to hold latest values

Tags: reactjs

> I have a form which shows data based on a date range. On first time load, > it shows data for last 1 hour. I am using react date > > > > picker to render start and end times. When user changes start and end > > > dates, below function is called. In this function, I am trying to set > > > state with user-selected start and end dates, but state always holds > > > previous start and end date value

```
  refreshTableOnDateChange(startDateSelected,endDateSelected) {
            this.setState({startDate: null, endDate: null});
             console.log("inside refreshTableOnDateChange this.state.startDate is", startDateSelected);
             console.log("inside refreshTableOnDateChange this.state.endDate is", endDateSelected);
             let startDateFormatted = startDateSelected.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
             let endDateFormatted = endDateSelected.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
              this.setState({startDate: startDateFormatted, endDate: endDateFormatted});
              this.forceUpdate();
              console.log("start date is", this.state.startDate);
             console.log("end date is", this.state.endDate);
             this.load(this.state.orderType);
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

setState does not immediately mutate state - From Reacts documentation:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

This code should be in render for you to see the update.:

```
      console.log("start date is", this.state.startDate);
```